# How to check alignment of text using selenium RC

Tags: python, selenium-rc

verify alignment of text or any other element in web page using selenium rc.
i use python,
is there any budy who can help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can utilize getAttribute command for example

```
String align = selenium.getAttribute("ele_locator@align");
```

Answer (score 0):

In case text alignment is coded directly in HTML you could do what you want using the `assertElementPresent()` method and a suitable XPath locator. For example to check the following text

```
<p id="paragraph" align="right">Text text text text text text text</p>
```

you could use

```
selenium.isElementPresent("//p[@id='paragraph' and @align='right']");
```